# Find a 4-digit number which, when multiplied by 4 yields the same number in reverse?

Tags: php

I am trying to write a simple program in *PHP* but cannot understand where I am going wrong - here is what I've tried so far:

```
function multipliedByReverseOrder() {
            for ($i = 1000; $i <=9999; $i++) {
                $value_a = $i;
                $value_b = $i*4;
               $new_value_a=$value_a;
                $new_value_b=$value_b;
                if($new_value_a==$value_a||$new_value_b==$value_b){

                }
            }
                $exact_value_a=$value_a*$new_value_a;
                $exact_value_a=$new_value_b;

                if ($exact_value_a == $exact_value_b) {
                echo $exact_value_a . "The Result is:";
            }

        }
```

Comment: The four digit no. is 2178  ,

2178 * 4 =  8712 @anik islam abhi

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse the string using `strrev` function.

```
function multipliedByReverseOrder() {

            for ($i = 1000; $i <=9999; $i++) {
                $a = $i;
                $b = $i*4;

                $c = strrev($b);

                if($a == $c)
                {
                    echo "Result is:". $a;
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: @softbd your welcome. If it helpful to you please accept it as answer.